# c linux jobs: Illegal option -n

Tags: linux, c, gcc

linux, gcc
Не получается вызвать jobs. В терминале получаю ошибку 
sh: 1: jobs: Illegal option -n
 При этом, если вызывать jobs, напрямую, через терминал, ошибок не получаю. Команды выполняются.
Как правильно вызвать и есть ли альтернатива для Си ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   system("jobs -n");
}
```

Comment: 1) а что вы хотите увидеть в выводе? 2) а вдруг список пуст? 3) что за -n? может -l ????

Comment: @Andrey ну введите в терминале jobs -n, что ошибку получите ?

Comment: Да, -n показывает были ли изменения с крайнего запроса., лично я получаю ошибку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jobs` — это встроенная команда оболочки (в частности `bash`), а не команда ОС.

> ```
> system("jobs -n");
> ```

По сути эта строка запускает `/bin/sh -c "jobs -n"`. т.е. оно запускает новую оболочку. И даже если бы оно работало без ошибки, оно бы вывело пустую строку.

А выдаёт ошибку оно скорей всего потому, что `/bin/sh` не является ссылкой на `bash` (скорей всего там `/bin/dash`) и не поддерживает его расширения, как ключ `-n` у команды jobs.

> Как правильно вызвать и есть ли альтернатива для Си?

Нет. Запросить список задач у родительской (или любой другой сторонней) оболочки в принципе невозможно, не только в Си, а в принципе какими-либо разумными простыми средствами.

Получение информации о какой-либо группе процессов напротив вполне возможно. см. `man ps` и `man proc`.

Comment: спасибо большое